# Disable/Enable TextBox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a group of `RadioButton` which will set off an `onclick` event.  The `pageLoad` and `onclick` event (`SecurityCheckedChanged`) work because the other `show`/`hide` JavaScript code works.  I've commented it out to give a minimal example.  However, setting disable `true`/`false` in `SecurityCheckedChanged` doesn't seem to work (it does work in `pageLoad` though).  Is what I'm doing correct or is there another way to enable/disable a `TextBox`?

JavaScript:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $("#<%= textBoxPassword.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", true);
    //more show/hide code
}

function SecurityCheckedChanged() {
    if ($("#<%= radWEP.ClientID %>").is(':checked')) {
        $("#<%= textBoxPassword.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", false);
        //more show/hide code
    }
    else if ($("#<%= radWPA.ClientID %>").is(':checked') || $("#<%= radWPA2.ClientID %>").is(':checked')) {
        $("#<%= textBoxPassword.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", false);
        //more show/hide code
    }
    else {
        $("#<%= textBoxPassword.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", true);
        //more show/hide code
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: left;">
    <asp:Localize ID="locPassword" runat="server" Text="Password:" meta:resourcekey="locPasswordRc1" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>


<div style="text-align: left;">
    <asp:RadioButton id="radNone" Text="None" Checked="True" meta:resourcekey="radNoneRc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupSecurity" runat="server" onclick="SecurityCheckedChanged()"/>

    <asp:RadioButton id="radWEP" Text="WEP" Checked="False" meta:resourcekey="radWepRc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupSecurity" runat="server" onclick="SecurityCheckedChanged()"/>

    <asp:RadioButton id="radWPA" Text="WPA" Checked="False" meta:resourcekey="radWpaRc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupSecurity" runat="server" onclick="SecurityCheckedChanged()"/>

    <asp:RadioButton id="radWPA2" Text="WPA2" Checked="False" meta:resourcekey="radWpa2Rc1"
        GroupName="RadioGroupSecurity" runat="server" onclick="SecurityCheckedChanged()"/>
</div>
```

NOTE:  Also, I understand I shouldn't intermix C# code here.  I'll get to cleaning that up a bit later.

Comment: Don't use `.attr("disabled", true/false)` for setting the disabled state. Use `.prop("disabled", true/false)`. Technically, you'd want to **remove** the attribute to enable it, but just stick to using `.prop()` - http://api.jquery.com/prop/ - it's the suggested method for setting states like this. Here's some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: @Ian It still doesn't work with `prop(...)`.  I forgot to mention that in the OP.  I just tried it again, but no dice.

Comment: Well then debug and make sure the right code is executing. And make sure the right elements are being selected